# Pull up to refresh in android RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swiperefreshlayout

I have used the SwipeRefreshLayout of v4 support library according to the following way:

```
 swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRefresh() {
            refreshItems();
        }
    });

   void refreshItems() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
        }
    }, 3000);
}
```

In this strategy, if I pull down the screen when first list item is visible then onRefresh() method is called.

[image]

This is called pull down to refresh. But I want the reverse effect. That is if I pull up the screen when last list item is visible then a method should be called or it should be notified anyway. Is it possible? If possible please provide me the way.

Comment: Can I ask you why do you want to accomplish that behaviour?

Comment: I want these because if number of data is huge and these data are loaded from server then I will load some data first time and more data will be loaded on pull up behaviour

Comment: Then you should look for **"Endless Scroll Listener"**, there are some libraries out there, or you can write your own `onScroll()` implementation of `OnScrollListener` to accomplish that.

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury see my answer below otherwise `Grender` is right you have to used `Endless Scroll Listener`.

Comment: Thanks Grender, Harshad. I will check it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Adapter class of RecyclerView/ListView while inflating last item you can put if statement and call a method.

Code if you are using **RecyclerView:-**

```
private boolean loading = true;
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) 
    {
        if(dy > 0) //check for scroll down
        {
            visibleItemCount = mLayoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = mLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) 
            {
                if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) 
                {
                    loading = false;
                    Log.v("...", "Last Item Wow !");
                    //Do pagination.. i.e. fetch new data
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Also add below code:-

```
LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;
mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

Comment: @KanchanChowdhury check my new answer

Answer (score 1):

you said it yourself, you are using SwipeRefreshLayout..
it is used in order to swipe to refresh,
it's not designed/capable to achieve your goal.

the way I see it you'll have to write your own custom view.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could check when the last item of the list is reached and trigger the animation+update.

Comment: Thanks. But it's not the desired behavior. If the last item is visible and I pull up again it will not be notified.

Answer (score 0):

In Android app Pull To Refresh aka SwipeRefreshLayout is used whenever we need to refresh the content’s of a view via a vertical swipe gesture. It accepts only one child means the component we want to refresh. It uses the listener mechanism to inform the listener who holds this component that a refresh event has occurred...

**Basic Pull To Refresh / SwipeRefreshLayout XML code:**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/simpleSwipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        < Add View's Here..../>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

See more with examples from http://abhiandroid.com/materialdesign/pulltorefresh.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of Vishwesh's answer

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
                // Prevents Swipe to Refresh if only scrolling up.  
                LinearLayoutManager llm = (LinearLayoutManager) recyclerView.getLayoutManager();
                int pos = llm.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if( pos != 0){
                    swipeRefresh.setEnabled(false);
                    swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    swipeRefresh.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I got same issue .so in on Refresh() methods i had   initialized again recycle view and 'endless Scroll Listener' it worked for me

```
@Override
  public void onRefresh() {
   Adapter = new Adapter(this, List, );
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(LayoutManager);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(Adapter);
    loadMoreData();

    recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new EndlessRecyclerOnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLoadMore() {
            loadMoreData();
        }
    });}
```